# I need to code (and understand) an ELISP script to automatically generate a file header

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this assignment due tomorrow where I have to learn how to customize BOTH emacs and vim. As a vim user, I feel a bit lost when it comes to editing a `.emacs` file. I found very few ressources online and none of them about generating file headers (I found ready-to-use plugins but that's not what I need).

Can anyone show me a good tutorial website or explain me the few things that'll get me started ? I'd be so grateful !!

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you precisely defined what "automatically" and "file header" mean in this instance.

Comment: For starters you might like to check the documentation for the `insert` function, and perhaps the `format` function. Also be aware that Emacs contains manuals and tutorials. Type `C-h i d` and you'll see both the "Elisp" and "Emacs Lisp Intro" manuals.

Comment: What @phils said. You'' need to learn some Emacs Lisp. Start with the *Emacs Lisp Intro* manual, which you'll find by doing **`C-h i`**. In addition to `insert` and `format`, you might want to use function `format-time-string`, to add or update a timestamp. You will need to learn about **comments** for the programming language that gets the file header (which is comments). If that language is Emacs Lisp, then see the Elisp manual, node [Library Headers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Library-Headers.html) - in Emacs: `C-h i m Elisp` `RET` `g library headers` `RET`.

Comment: As the question was never clarified and the deadline has passed, I suggest that this be closed (as "unclear what you're asking").